# How to download a live video from the internet

Tags: windows, linux, video, download, download-manager

I would like to know how to download a live video from the internet,

My guess is that I could use [downloadhelper.net](http://www.downloadhelper.net/) or the [Video DownloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/) add-on. If not, how could I do that on Windows, Linux and Mac?

Answer (score 2):

The Video DownloadHelper add-on does work for both standard video files and Flash. On Windows, I use Internet Download Manager to download all video (it has browser integration). On Mac I use video DownloadHelper.

**The above method only works for non-live video.**, e.g. YouTube. You can't really download live streaming content as the entire file doesn't exist. You can only capture what is coming to your computer.

I used one of the tools listed here before – can't remember which one: [How to download streaming video and audio](http://emoney.al.ru/capture-streaming-video-and-audio/)

Or have a look [here](http://all-streaming-media.com/record-video-stream/).

Comment: Thankyou for pointing out slhck, mybad. Answer edited accordingly

Comment: Since Linux is tagged I would add:
"Broadband streams like live streaming video, streaming news video, streaming movies, streaming music videos can be captured, recorded, downloaded with special software: Stream Downloader (also called Stream Ripper), Stream Capture software, Stream Recorder. Online videos can also be recorded from screen with screen recorders (also called screen capture software, screencasting software) and online music, radio programs and audio books can be recorded from your sound card."  From chmod's first link above.  I think StreamRipper is supported on many distros

Answer (score 1):

Try Firefox extension Flashgot. It'll notify you when there's some video or music on the webpage.

Or you can try Firebug. It's a debugging tool but maybe the best tool to download video. After installing Firebug, press F12 to open it and active "Net" panel. Then go to your video page. You'll see requests logged in Firebug. Scroll down to find the video file (you can see its extension, or if it's still loading and taking a long time to download) and copy the request location to a download manager.

This may not work if the site checks cookie before streaming video.

Answer (score 0):

**2021 answer:**

I just tried Video DownloadHelper and it is really crap today (it was working very well in 2008-2012 for me). It does not show in Chrome. In Firefox it works but it asks you to install the Download Companion. I tried downloading this video: [Cosmos Laundromat](https://vimeo.com/137931051) - it took like 5 minutes to download then it says "Aggregating" and that takes one hour!

Then I tried [JDownloader 2](https://jdownloader.org) and it downloaded the video in 720p resolution in just one minute. Quick and easy.